# Did Antifa Exist as a Group in the USA Between 2000 and 2017?

Tags: united-states, politics

The first major use of the word "Antifa" in modern times (that I can find) is something [on Breitbart from 4/21/2017](https://www.breitbart.com/tech/2017/04/21/berkeley-mayor-is-member-of-antifa-facebook-group-that-organized-riots/), claiming that the mayor of Berkeley was a member of an anti-fascist group 'By Any Means Necessary'. This was significant, because up to that point, the 4/15/2017 protest of Breitbart columnist Milo Yiannopoulos was just said to be comprised of 'multiple liberal groups', which is no big surprise in a town like Berkeley.

The first [documented use](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/15/us/politics/alt-left-alt-right-glossary.html) of 'alt-left' in modern times was when Trump used it in his famous 'both sides' speech following the Charlotteville protest.

After that, use of the word Antifa [blew through the roof](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&geo=US&q=antifa), and this bogeyman has been used by the alt-Right to justify their actions ever since.

My question is, **is Antifa (under that name) documented to exist as an organized group at any point between 2000 and 2017?** Was this bogeyman created by Breitbart to have a documented foe against which they could rally? Or has a group large enough to pose a threat to the alt-right existed in the background for decades, only now driven to the forefront?

Comment: I have bolded my question and added my criteria to the title.

Comment: Are you looking for antifascist movements *per se* or *a group named "Antifa" specifically*? The [ARA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Racist_Action) existed from 1987 to 2013, for example.

Comment: Antifa specifically. I can't find anything before that Breitbart article using that word, which makes it difficult to see if people's self-naming of 'Antifa' was in response to that article.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/ is very good at word use and origin. I'd ask there.

Comment: I know you tagged united-states, but are you only looking for groups that explicitly called themselves 'Antifa' in the US? According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/words-were-watching-antifa) and [Oxford](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2017/12/15/antifa-word-of-the-year-2017-shortlist/) 'antifa' comes from some German movements and only started being widely applied to US anti-fascist groups in 2017, but many of the groups that now comprise 'Antifa' existed prior to that.

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

Comment: This question also needs work to reduce the political posturing and focus on the question.

Comment: I still think the OP is a bit confused about the fact that "Antifa" can be both a specific organisation *and* an umbrella term for anti-fascist movements and organizations. The data the OP is looking for -- the existence / non-existence of a specific group of that name -- does neither confirm nor refute the implied claims; that the term was circulated in the US by Breitbart, that the group was large / a "threat" or not, or whatever

Comment: Wikipedia seems to answer the question with references (similar to @Giter's) so there's little value adding more.

Comment: Perhaps see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_City_Antifa founded in 2007?